# AngularJS. What's directive I need to repeat html tag if variable is not collection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-repeat does repeat on arrays. But but how do I repeat `<table></table>` no of time by value in my variable?

Answer (score 0):

create a range filter like below

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);
    for (var i=0; i<total; i++)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
});
```

and using that you can do ng-repeat like below,

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:myCountVariable">
  do something
</div>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.myCountVariable = 10;
```